# What do you think is the best way to say sharpshooter in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, new-latin

I'm imagining a scenario where the Roman Empire lasted a little longer through the development of firearms, and would want a word to describe the concept of a sharpshooter.

I'm not sure if this sort of word should be sourced entirely from Latin, Greek, or imagined as borrowed from a Germanic language.  Does anyone have input?

So far, I've come up with aciārius (aciēs + ārius, “one who fights with their keen senses”) but I'm not at all confident with my approach so far.